# sort lowercase letters before uppercase with Icomparer

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, icomparer

I have a ListCollectionView which holds a collection of scene objects and I need to sort it by scene Number  (Scene.SceneNumber) which is a string containing numbers and letters and I need to sort it in a very specific order. First by number then by letter with the lowercase letters first, then the uppercase.

The list needs to look like this:

```
1
1pt1
1pt2
1A
1Apt1
2
2pt1
2Apt1
3
...
```

This is what I have so far:

```
public class SceneComparer : IComparer
{
    private readonly Regex sceneRegEx = new Regex(@"(\d+)(\w+)?", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        Scene sceneX = x as Scene;
        Scene sceneY = y as Scene;

        var firstSceneMatches = this.sceneRegEx.Matches(sceneX.SceneNumber);
        var secondSceneMatches = this.sceneRegEx.Matches(sceneY.SceneNumber);

        var matchesCount = Math.Min(firstSceneMatches.Count, secondSceneMatches.Count);
        for (var i = 0; i < matchesCount; i++)
        {
            var firstSceneMatch = firstSceneMatches[i];
            var secondSceneMatch = secondSceneMatches[i];

            var firstSceneNumeric = Convert.ToInt32(firstSceneMatch.Groups[1].Value);
            var secondSceneNumeric = Convert.ToInt32(secondSceneMatch.Groups[1].Value);
            if (firstSceneNumeric != secondSceneNumeric)
            {
                return firstSceneNumeric - secondSceneNumeric;
            }

            var firstSceneAlpha = firstSceneMatch.Groups[2].Value;
            var secondSceneAlpha = secondSceneMatch.Groups[2].Value;
            if (firstSceneAlpha != secondSceneAlpha)
            {
                return string.CompareOrdinal(firstSceneAlpha, secondSceneAlpha);
            }
        }
        return firstSceneMatches.Count - secondSceneMatches.Count;
     }
}
```

this results in following list

```
1
1A
1Apt1
1pt1
1pt2
2
2Apt1
2pt1
...
```

But I need the lowercase letters before the uppercase letters. How do I do this?

Comment: What if there would be `sceneComparer.Compare(null, null)` or `sceneComparer.Compare(1, "qwerty")`? Don't use `as` without following null-checking. Also, cosinder implementation of `Comparer<Scene>` instead of directly implementing non-generic interface. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You **really** need to [stop deleting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270370/sorting-objects-with-icomparer) and just reposting the same basic question. If you need to make a change, just click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45273455/edit) link and modify the post. Repeatedly deleting your posts will eventually get you banned from asking questions for a time, and when it's revealed that you have been habitually abusing Stack Overflow, your questions will very likely earn down-votes you'd rather not have.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the work `var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(x => x);`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = new[] { "1pt1", "2", "2pt1","1", "1pt2", "1A", "1Apt1",  "2Apt1", "3" };

    var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(x => x);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sortedItems));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Downvotes don't need comments... If you feel need to discuss the post - ask question on meta (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)... Also in this particular case "I posted wall of code as an answer without any explanations and some $##$@ downvoted my post" may not go very well... May be good idea to search meta for recommendation on whether code-only answers are welcome.